# Matplotlib: add more colors to the default colors in axes.prop_cycle() manually?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colors

I just increase my sample to 12 and found `axes.prop_cycle()` has only 10 colors by default (I think it is `tab10`.). So I got `IndexError: list index out of range`.

My simplified code. Each sample value is represented in each row of matrix

```
matrix = np.random.randint(25, size=(12, 4))

for p in xrange(12):
  ax_eachp = plt.subplot2grid((protcount, 1), (p, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
  ax_eachp.plot(matrix[p], color=colors[p])
```

Can I just add 2 more colors manually if I want to remain first 10 colors in `tab10`? or how to change to other [qualitative color maps](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)?

Comment: In case the duplicate does not help, please edit the question as to why that would not be the case.

Comment: I just edited my question - if I want to remain first 10 colors in `tab10`, can I just add 2 more colors manually? Instead of changing to `jet` like in the previous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the linked question [Python Matplotlib/Basemap Color Cycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676657/python-matplotlib-basemap-color-cycling?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows, you may set the axes' `prop_cycle` to include those colors you like.

Here you can take the tab10 colors and add two more colors to the list of colors to be used in the `prop_cycle`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = list(plt.cm.tab10(np.arange(10))) + ["crimson", "indigo"]
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)

for i in range(12):
    ax.plot([0,1],[i,i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, since in the case from the question, you anyway loop over the colors, there is actually no need for a cycler. The following produces the same result as above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = list(plt.cm.tab10(np.arange(10))) + ["crimson", "indigo"]

for i in range(12):
    ax.plot([0,1],[i,i], color=colors[i])

plt.show()
```