# Error in ploting dataframe groupby result - color repeated for legends with more than ten items

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, pandas-groupby

I am building a KPrototypes clutering model. I have the data clustered into 7 groups. Right now I would like to validate the result so I am looking into how each group behaves for each feature though groupby and visualization.

-- If you have other recommanded ways other than visualization, please do share with me as well.

Here is the problem. I have more than 20 features and when I try to plot the result, I get seven subplots that look like this.

`user_general.groupby(by='classification').plot(figsize =(15,15))`

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

etc.

As you can see in the legend, the color is repeated for every ten features. I looked into the dataframe.plot() document from pandas but I did not find any solution. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233855/matplotlib-add-more-colors-to-the-default-colors-in-axes-prop-cycle-manually